# C++ cURL "empty reply from server" every time

Tags: c++, curl

I am trying to write a C++ program to read from a website using cURL.  I have started with using the code from the cURL example simple.c.  If I use that code exactly, no matter what URL I try to access, I obtain error #52: "empty reply from server".  This is for any URL I try.  If I use cURL from the command line, it seems to work fine.

The verbose response of my program is:

```
*About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
* Trying 74.125.91.99...* connected
*connected to www.google.com (74.125.91.99) port 80 (#0)
>GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*

* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
* server returned nothing (no headers, no data)
*Closing connection #0
```

The code is:

```
CURL *curl; 
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init(); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com"); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Comment: That code works perfectly for me.  Outputs the page to STDOUT without a problem. (With the exception that `TRUE` wasn't defined, but using `1` worked)

Comment: It looks perfectly fine to be, too

Comment: Aaaaarghh, try to remove the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` flag. Some versions (I can't remember which exactly) have awful bug using CURLOPT_VERBOSE flag, set to 1. Try without it. Also, which is the curl'a version?

Comment: I tried removing the verbose flag, and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Empty reply from server" means that libcurl didn't receive *any* response from the server after it sent off its request. In HTTP every request always gets something back so this is not even responding with HTTP and is thus a rather sever error.

You use a very old libcurl so possibly you're experiencing a bug that existed back then.

Other possible reasons for this is that something in your network/setup is preventing this from working, like a firewall.

Comment: I will try a newer version to see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Upgrading to the most recent version (7.21.6) seemed to fix the problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I lost a couple hours debugging an empty response from curl, so I'm sharing here to hopefully prevent the same from happening to others.

I noticed that OPTIONS calls were returned with the "Empty reply from server" error in both the browser and from curl on my machine, but worked fine from a colleague's.  When I tried to telnet to port 80 on the web server, the connection would immediately close as soon as I hit ENTER after typing the "OPTIONS /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1" line.  Doing an "lsof -i | grep telnet" (with the telnet session open, before typing the OPTIONS line), I saw that my telnet session was to something local, NOT the server I'd specified.  I knew something REALLY strange was going on then.  Turns out it was because I had Cisco AnyConnect VPN software installed.  The VPN need not be running--merely having it installed was enough for it in intercept my traffic.  Nasty.  A little googling turned up this page, which talks more about the issue:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2559-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client-may-block-cors-ajax-options-requests.htm

So, short story is: it might not be the server...something local could be intercepting and blocking your network traffic.